# Parity wallet: how to reverse execute function?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

While attempting to transfer ETH from my Parity wallet (multisig contract) to a cryptocurrency exchange, I have apparently taken the wrong approach and now it seems my ETH is stuck somewhere in the wallet (multisig contract) but not visible to me.

My actions leading to this problem were as follows:

- Opened my contract in Parity wallet
- Clicked the "execute" tab
- In the "from" field I chose my account (owner of the wallet)
- In the "function" field I chose "execute"
- In the "to address" field I listed the exchange ETH address
- In the "value" field I listed the amount of ETH I wanted to transfer
- I left the data field empty

The resulting transaction came up on etherscan as follows:

- From: my account address
- To: contract: my wallet address
- Value: 0 ether (this I don't understand)
- Gas used by TXN: 51271
- Input data: `Function: execute(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) ***` followed by the binary data that includes the exchange ETH address and on the second line I see the amount of ETH I actually wanted to transfer

The problem with this is:

- The ETH never arrived at the exchange's address (they've already stated they can't help me with this problem, merely referring to their ETH address on etherscan and saying; "look, there's no ETH coming in from you")
- The ETH was deducted from my wallet

I'm looking for answers to 2 questions:

- What did I do wrong in my attempt to send the ETH via Parity?
- How (if at all) can I retrieve my ETH?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
For security reasons please understand I'd rather not list the transaction or my addresses here.

Comment: Which exchange is that? Could you share the transaction ID?

Comment: For security reasons I'd rather not share the transaction id or my addresses. The exchange was Kraken though.

Comment: Is it a multi-sig wallet? Please open the wallet and check if there are any pending requests awaiting signature. Feel free to share screenshots, just hide sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It is a multi-sig wallet indeed. There are no pending requests when I open "Signer". When I open the wallet the "events" list is empty as well. The transaction has showed up on etherscan though, it's been over 3 weeks ago now since I sent it.
Any thoughts as to what functions I can try to call on the contract to get that ETH back?

Comment: You can take a look at the source code of the execute() function in the contract. (It's probably equivalent to this -- https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/master/js/src/contracts/snippets/enhanced-wallet.sol -- but you may have used an older version.) The code just emits the "ConfirmationNeeded" event if more signatures are needed. It sounds like that may have happened to you, but it's hard to help without more information.

Comment: @AgentME, the source code is a bit different, it's the same as this commit: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/commit/63137b15482344ff9df634c086abaabed452eadc?diff=unified
Does that information suffice for you to make some suggestions?

Comment: I hope you're mistaken because that version was vulnerable to an issue that let others steal funds.
If you view the wallet's address on etherscan.io and look at the transaction you called on it, did that transaction trigger a subtransaction to send the funds, or does your wallet address still have the ether?
If it still has the ether, it sounds like you didn't have the transaction approved by the other owners. Your question entirely lacks any mention of actions from the other owners so it's hard to help.

Comment: I feel bad about not elaborating a bit about the vulnerable version: you can tell if you are on the vulnerable version of the wallet if it contains the line "function initWallet(address[] _owners, uint _required, uint _daylimit) {" instead of "function initMultiowned(address[] _owners, uint _required) only_uninitialized {".